# How to add title text to two annotated heat maps from figurefactory?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, data-science

I am using plotly to create two annotated heatmaps. For some reason, I cannot add title_text when there is two figures present. The Following gives me an error saying `Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Heatmap: 'title'`

```
# Data Visualization

import plotly.figure_factory as ff


def confusion_matrix(class_indices):
    train_z = [[2, 4],
               [2, 4]]

    val_z = [[6, 8],
             [6, 8]]

    x = ['True (1)', 'False (0)']
    y = ['Negative', 'Positive']

    # Turn each item in z into a string for annotation only
    def string_annotation_converter(z_data):
        z_text = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in z_data]
        return z_text

    # set up figure
    train_confusion_mat = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(train_z, x=x, y=y,
                                                      colorscale='Viridis',
                                                      annotation_text=string_annotation_converter(train_z))
    train_confusion_mat.update_layout(title_text=f'Training CM - {str(class_indices)}')

    val_confusion_mat = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(val_z, x=x, y=y,
                                                    colorscale='Viridis',
                                                    annotation_text=string_annotation_converter(val_z),
                                                    title_text=f'Validation CM - {str(class_indices)}')
    val_confusion_mat.update_layout(title_text=f'Validation CM - {str(class_indices)}')


confusion_matrix('title')
```

However, when I remove the second figure I want included, it suddenly works? Why is that and what could I do to work around this issue?:

```
# Data Visualization

import plotly.figure_factory as ff


def confusion_matrix(class_indices):
    train_z = [[2, 4],
               [2, 4]]

    val_z = [[6, 8],
             [6, 8]]

    x = ['True (1)', 'False (0)']
    y = ['Negative', 'Positive']

    # Turn each item in z into a string for annotation only
    def string_annotation_converter(z_data):
        z_text = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in z_data]
        return z_text

    # set up figure
    train_confusion_mat = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(train_z, x=x, y=y,
                                                      colorscale='Viridis',
                                                      annotation_text=string_annotation_converter(train_z))
    train_confusion_mat.update_layout(title_text=f'Training CM - {str(class_indices)}')


confusion_matrix('title')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your second figure tries to pass a value to a `title_text` property of `ff.create_annotated_heatmap`. As the error says this isn't a valid property.

You don't pass this parameter to the first graph, that's why it does work.

So change this:

```
val_confusion_mat = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
    val_z,
    x=x,
    y=y,
    colorscale="Viridis",
    annotation_text=string_annotation_converter(val_z),
    title_text=f"Validation CM - {str(class_indices)}",
)
```

to this:

```
val_confusion_mat = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
    val_z,
    x=x,
    y=y,
    colorscale="Viridis",
    annotation_text=string_annotation_converter(val_z),
)
```

You're already updating the `title_text` of both figures through `update_layout` so you only have to make the adjustment mentioned above.